# SSH using git - private and public key

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm new to ssh and having some trouble with using private and public keys to connect to host. Currently, I use simple syntax:

**Plain SSH in git**

```
ssh username@host
```

and it works like a charm, but now at my office, I don't have direct access to shell. I have to use private and public keys, I used putty/putty-Gen as well, but that didn't work out, is there any way that I could use git to connect to a server using private and public keys?

Comment: When you say you don't have direct access to the shell - what tool are you trying to use to clone your repository?

Comment: I'm not trying to clone any repository, i'm only trying to connect to my website's server

Comment: How is your question related to Git? Are you just trying to SSH into the server? If so, ensure you include `-i <path_to_private_key>` with your `ssh` command to make sure it's using the key you want.

Comment: I want to ssh into server via git bash using private key and public key

Comment: Okay - "git bash" (assuming you're on a Windows machine?) is for your purposes, not really related to Git at all. To SSH into a server, you just need to make sure that your public key is in the `authorized_keys` file on the remote server, and that you're using the right private key in your `ssh` command. What error do you receive when you try to SSH in? Can you run the command with `-vvv` to get some extra output/logging?

Answer (score 3):

You need to authorize the public key contained on your office machine with your host.

Append the contents of your (office machine) `~/.ssh/<id>.pub` to your (remote host) `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file